# astropy: How can I check that an argument has the correct unit

Tags: python-3.x, astropy

In Python's `astropy`, how can I check that a function's argument not only has the correct unit, but has a unit at all?

I'm familiar with `is_equivalent()`, so to check that `M` has units of mass, I can say

```
assert M.unit.is_equivalent(u.g)
```

which returns `True` if, say, `M = 1e12 * u.Msun`. But if `M` doesn't have any units at all — e.g. if I accidentally pass `M = 1e12` — I get

```
AttributeError: 'Quantity' object has no '_normalize_equivalencies' member
```

One way to do it would be to first multiply `M` by e.g. `(u.m/u.m)`, which equals `Unit(dimensionless)` and won't alter `M` if it *does* have a unit, while it would convert a number like `1e12` into `<Quantity 1.e+12>` which can then be checked without giving an error.

This doesn't seem like the right way to do it, though. Is there a better way?

Comment: Note, if you specifically want to check the units of *arguments to a function* you can use the [`quantity_input`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.quantity_input.html#astropy.units.quantity_input) decorator with that function.

Comment: @Iguananaut Excellent! Thanks a lot! It's a bit more characters to write, but more Pythonic I guess, and gives you more varieties of catching errors. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if your goal is specifically to check the units of function arguments, you can use the [`quantity_input`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.units.quantity_input.html#astropy.units.quantity_input) utility decorator which is specifically for this purpose (and will raise either `ValueError` or `TypeError` or `UnitsError` as appropriate, which are typically more appropriate exceptions for invalid function arguments than a bare `AssertionError`).

I particularly like the Python 3-specific syntax for this which makes use of function annotations.  Here are some examples:

```py
>>> from astropy import units as u
>>> @u.quantity_input
... def my_function(M: u.g):
...     print(M)
```

Correct units:

```py
>>> my_function(1e12*u.Msun)                                                
1000000000000.0 solMass
>>> my_function(1e12*u.g)                                                   
1000000000000.0 g
```

Examples with incorrect arguments:

```py
>>> my_function(1e12)
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: Argument 'M' to function 'my_function' has no 'unit' attribute. You may want to pass in an astropy Quantity instead.
```

```py
>>> my_function(1e12*u.dimensionless_unscaled)
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
UnitsError: Argument 'M' to function 'my_function' must be in units convertible to 'g'.
```

If you have many functions that take `M` as an argument which must have mass units, you could also make a shorthand for it like:

```py
>>> M_mass = u.quantity_input(M=u.g)
>>> @M_mass
... def my_function(M):
...     print(M)
```

The same approach can be used for functions of multiple arguments in different units.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!